# Crystal Reports Summary field with sum of amounts from SQL command

Tags: sql, sum

I have a sub-report that returns the following....

```
SELECT  
    SUM (SorDetail.MPrice) OVER (PARTITION BY SorDetail.SalesOrder,     [CusSorDetailMerch+].InvoiceGrouping) AS GroupTotal,
    SorDetail.SalesOrder,
    SorDetail.SalesOrderLine,
    SorDetail.MStockCode, 
    SorDetail.MStockDes, 
    [CusSorDetailMerch+].InvoiceGrouping, 
    SorDetail.MOrderQty, 
    SorDetail.MPrice, 
    [CusSorDetailMerch+].SerialNumber 
FROM     
    SorDetail 
INNER JOIN
    [CusSorDetailMerch+] ON SorDetail.SalesOrder = [CusSorDetailMerch+].SalesOrder 
                         AND SorDetail.SalesOrderLine = [CusSorDetailMerch+].SalesOrderInitLine
WHERE        
    (dbo.SorDetail.SalesOrder = '000000000' + '{?SalesOrder}') 
    AND (dbo.SorDetail.SalesOrderInitLine = '{?Line}')
ORDER BY
    [CusSorDetailMerch+].InvoiceGrouping
```

It returns this which is what I want:

[Data Returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U61ho.png)

What I just cant seem to do id to add a column that sums the different groups and separates the groups like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr9n8.png)

I have tried everything but cannot get the sums individually

Comment: Can you please clarify - do you want to add subtotals by `InvoiceGrouping`? If so, that's probably needs to be a separate query as subtotal schema (set of columns) do not match your main request schema.

Comment: Instead of using a subquery for it you can use a grouping functionality of crystal-reports itself to add that subtotal, no need to change your query. Fast search on google: https://www.universalclass.com/articles/computers/how-to-group-data-in-crystal-reports.htm